# inserting in binary tree doesn't work using java

Tags: java, search, data-structures, tree, binary

I'm currently learning about trees using java
and i have some errors going on here
in the insertion of items in a binary tree
I don't why it doesn't work

this is the code:
tree node:

```
public class TNode {
    int data;
    TNode left;
    TNode right;

    public TNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

tree class:

```
public class Tree {
    TNode root;

    public Tree(){
        root = null;
    }

    public TNode insertNode(TNode item, int d) {
        if (item == null) {
            return new TNode(d);
        }

         if (d < item.data) {
            item.left = insertNode(item, d);
        }

        if (d > item.data) {
            item.right = insertNode(item, d);
        } else {
            return item;
        }

        return item;
    }

    public void add(int d) {
        insertNode(root, d);
    }
}
```

Whenever I add an item the root remains null with no right or left items 
if someone can help I'll be really thankful

Comment: ..because, you never assign root (to something different than `null`), plz do (probably best design) in `add` method: `if (root == null) { root = insertNode(root, d); } else { insertNode(root, d); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` is always null because you never assign value to it.

you can add to the beginning of your method check and assign it

```
public TNode insertNode(TNode item, int d){
    if(item == null){
        TNode node = new TNode(d);
        if (root == null) { 
            root = node;
        }
        return node
    }
    ... rest of method isn't changed...
```

Also when you are recursing you should make a call with a proper child node instead of always calling with `item`, so for example first case would be:

```
    item.left = insertNode(item.left, d);
```

For second case you would just use `item.right` instead.

Comment: "root = nude;" should probably be "root = node;" xD nice one

Answer (score 1):

Fine code, but recursing does not step further

```
item.left = insertNode(item.left, d);
item.right = insertNode(item.right, d);
```

And the initial root is not updated:

```
root = insertNode(root, d);
```

The else part or final return is superfluous.

---

***Something on the code style***

`insertNode` has a node as input, and returns the updated node value, hence the call "pattern" should look like

```
X = insertNode(X, d); // X is some expression
```

This is because java can never assign to the passed argument expression: it has no pass-by-reference, but pass-by-value; `f(x)` never assigns to `x`.